# Copy cells with formulas in macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a excel spreadsheet with 2 sheets.
In the first sheet, I got some values, when I click on a button then in the second sheet the following happens
1. a new row is inserted at the top
2. the data from the first sheet is copied.

However, there are some columns with formulas after the copied cells, and I dont know how to do in vbscript to copy those formulas after your insert a new row.

```
Sub Trade1()
    Sheets("Trades").Select
    Rows("2:2").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("A2:R2").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("A2").Select
    Dim fromRange As Range, toRange As Range
    Set fromRange = Sheets("Enter Trade").Range("B2:B20")
    Set toRange = Sheets("Trades").Range("A2")
    fromRange.Copy
    toRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After inserting a new row 2 (so that it's contents are now on row 3), I would copy row 3 back to row 2 (basically make a duplicate), and then override the values with the data you want to move from sheet 'Enter Trade' range B2:B20, like so:

```
Sub Trade_Button_Click()

    Dim btn As Button
    Dim wsEntry As Worksheet
    Dim wsTrades As Worksheet

    Set wsEntry = Sheets("Enter Trade")
    Set wsTrades = Sheets("Trades")
    Set btn = wsEntry.Buttons(Application.Caller)

    wsTrades.Rows(2).Insert
    wsTrades.Rows(3).Copy wsTrades.Rows(2)
    With Intersect(wsEntry.Range("A2", wsEntry.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).EntireRow, wsEntry.Columns(btn.TopLeftCell.Column))
        wsTrades.Range("A2").Resize(, .Rows.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(.Value)
    End With

    Set wsTrades = Nothing
    Set wsEntry = Nothing

End Sub
```

I have uploaded a modified version of your provided workbook here: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bz-nM5djZBWYa0R5T2hXMERabjg/edit?usp=sharing

In the modified version, I have mapped all of the Enter buttons to the above macro.  When I click on a button, it copies over the correct column's values and also copies the formulas in the rest of the table within sheet 'Trades' successfully.

Comment: file is here: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B77YRWgG0ik8RW1YR2hhSzF3aEE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I have modified the provided file and updated my answer.  The modified file is available in the edited answer.

Comment: thanks a lot, I tried it, thanks for reducing the code of the button. However, when I press the button, and then I go to the trades sheet, the formulas are not there, see screeenshot http://screencast.com/t/KsHIJvPjwx

Comment: In your provided workbook, there are no formulas for those columns until row 6.  So copying row 3 where there aren't any formulas doesn't bring them into the newly inserted row 2.  Why aren't the formulas all the way up to the top?  Just copy them up manually once, and the code will take care of the rest.  I also notice that you don't actually need rows 2:20 to be brought over.  I have edited my answer to have it only bring over the populated rows so that it doesn't override the formulas with blank cells.